# How to exclude JavaScript files generated by TypeScript from Find ... in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I use WebStorm and I have some JavaScript files generated by TypeScript in my project. I would like to exclude them from Search ..., so I don't modify them accidentally.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Which "Search" you mean in particular (there are different kinds of "find" action in IDE).

Comment: Find in Path ... and Open file (Ctrl + Shift + N) ... @LazyOne

Answer (score 0):

**"Find in Path"** -- create and use [custom Scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/scopes.html?search=scope) (this scope should contain only desired files -- e.g. include all & exclude all unwanted files)

You can also use `!` in [File mask field](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/find-and-replace-in-path.html?search=find) to exclude certain file types.

---

**Navigate to ...** family of actions -- AFAIK you cannot, unless such generated files are located in separate folders which can be marked as Excluded .. or you want to exclude ALL files of such type (use filter icon then).

You check these tickets for further info/ideas (including those mentioned in "Related" section):

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12345
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12494
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12479
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17579
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20856

Star/Vote/Comment them to get notified on any progress.

Comment: This will exclude all *.js and *.js.map from src/ and test/ - "(file:src//**||file:test//**)&&!(file:src//*.js||file:src//*.js.map||file:test//*.js||file:test//*.js.map)"